# É possível listar as colunas utilizadas em um SELECT no mysqli PHP?

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

Eu tenho a query

```
SELECT coluna1, coluna2... FROM tabela
```

Gostaria de saber se há algum método na classe `mysqli` para retornar essas colunas que foram utilizadas na consulta, mesmo que a `query` não retorne registros. Em uma `query` que retorne registros eu posso simplesmente utilizar `array_keys()` no método `fetch_assoc()`. Mas não posso se a `query` não retornar registros, já que não haverão índices.

Preciso fazer isso pois é uma `query` grande, e gostaria que tal processo fosse feito de maneira dinâmica.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para recuperar as colunas utilizadas no select use a função/método [fetch_fields()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-fields.php) que retorna as informações como nome, tipo, tamanho etc das colunas.

```
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'usuario', 'senha', 'base');

$result = $db->query('SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM tabela');

$fields  = $result->fetch_fields();

foreach($fields as $item){
    echo $item->name .'<br>';
}
```

O retorno é um objeto com as seguintes propriedades:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [name] => col1
    [orgname] => col1
    [table] => tabela
    [orgtable] => tabela
    [def] => 
    [db] => base
    [catalog] => def
    [max_length] => 0
    [length] => 1
    [charsetnr] => 8
    [flags] => 0
    [type] => 254
    [decimals] => 0
)
```

Comment: Resolveu! Muito obrigado